# In vim inoremap jj <Esc> prints <Esc> instead of returning to normal mode

Tags: vim, archlinux

Pressing tab in the command line also just prints out ^] instead of auto completing. My .vimrc file is as follows:

```
filetype plugin indent on       " show existing tab with 4 spaces width
set tabstop=4                   " use 4 spaces width for indenting
set shiftwidth=4                " same but when you use tab
set expandtab                   " use spaces instead of tabs
filetype plugin on              " for syntax highlighting
syntax on                       " syntax highlighting
set number                      " show line numbers
inoremap jj <Esc>
```

Also I am running a fairly new install of Arch linux. I have tried in Konsole, XTerm and Termite but return the same results. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have paste mode turned on? insert mappings are disabled in paste mode.

Comment: I haven't done anything with paste mode so if it is set to whatever the default is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to turn off vi compatibility. `inoremap` is not available in compatible mode.

Also, I notice that you have `filetype plugin on` twice. You don't need to do that; you can probably eliminate the second one.

```
set nocompatible
filetype plugin indent on
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
syntax on
set number
inoremap jj <Esc>
```